# Why this JMock test is failing?

Tags: java, jmock

The class structures are as follows:

```
public interface Sender {
    void send(String note);
} 

public interface Agent {
    void sendNote(String note);
}

public class Emailer implements Sender {
    void send(String note) {
        //...do something
    }
}

 public class EmailAgent implements Agent {
    void sendNote(String note) {
        Sender sender = new Emailer();
        sender.send();
    }
}
```

I have implemented my JMock/JUnit test like this:

```
@Rule
public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

Sender sender = context.mock(Sender.class);

@Test
public void test1() {
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        exactly(1).of(sender).send("test"); 
    }});

    new EmailAgent().sendNote("test");
}
```

For some reasons, the above is failing because it said `sender.send()` is never invoked. How is this possible?

Comment: Your `new EmailClient()` knows nothing about mock `sender` object. If you were passing it into the method, either via constructor or method itself it would behave as you want it. Instead you are creating mock `sender` in test class and another one within `test1` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmailAgent doesn't use a Sender that it gets from anywhere; it creates its own. So:

- Ihe test creates a mocked Sender (call it "a").
- It then invokes `sendNote`, which creates a second Sender (call it "b").
- That method returns, and the test then checks that "a" had `send` invoked -- which it didn't, since the EmailClient didn't know about it.

Rather than creating a Sender within `EmailAgent.sendNote`, you should create a constructor in EmailAgent that takes a Sender and stores it in an instance field, and then uses that field in `sendNote`. Then, the test passes its mocked sender to the EmailAgent.